# Can't POST through React to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to use `fetch()` to POST React form data to my Rails API, but my error within the Network tab of chrome dev tools returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /undefined/cars</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in the console states the "Unexpected token '<'" indicating that my response is being sent as HTML instead of JSON, but I'm not sure why it's not converting.

Here's my fetch request:

```
export const createCar = car => {
return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/cars`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ car: car })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(car => {
        dispatch(addCar(car))
        dispatch(resetCarForm())
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error + 'createCar POST failed'))
}
```

}

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to send a request to `/undefined/cars`, so `API_URL` might be `undefined` in your code. Can you include all the relevant code where you define `API_URL`?

Comment: Good catch, here's my code: `const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;`

Comment: Cool. Then it might be that you don't set the `REACT_APP_API_URL` environment variable correctly. Do you have a `.env` file in the root of your project with e.g. `REACT_APP_API_URL=https://example.com` in it?

Comment: The only instances of `.env` in my project are in the `.gitignore` and within my `serviceWorker.js`. Should I just create a new file or do I need to run some command?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to run `npm i dotenv`, then add a `.env` file to my root and add the following:

`REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001/`